# How to add simple product to basket if this product is child of configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, addtocart, simple-product, superattribute

How to add simple product to basket if this product is child of configurable product ?

How I can get `super_attributes` of **simple product** ( I got ID ) to make it ?

An example: I have T-shirts `(id 1)` configurable product.

And I got `XL (id 5)`, `L (id 6)` versions of this product.

I want **add to shopping cart id 5**, but I cannot make it without `requestInfo (super_attributes)` when I'm using `addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)`

Comment: To add simple product of configurable product you can refer bellow link: http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/adding-the-child-product-to-the-cart/

Answer (score 1):

Ok , I got it.

Steps.

```
1. load child product object.

2. load parent id from child id.

3. load parent product object.
```

`4. get parent array of attributes`

($parent->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($parent);)

```
5. Make loop for array of attributes

6. $attributeId = $attribute['attribute_id']

7. And use in loop getAttributeRawValue method for value of attribute.

8. $cart->addProduct($parent, array('qty => 4, 'super_attribute' => array($attributeId => $value)));

9. $cart->save();

10. Open your beer
```

Comment: hello amit can you explain it with code for magento2

Comment: Does the `getAddUrl` take the same params? We are trying to add products to the cart by a direct URL (via ajax)